# How to escape hash in kendo nested Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I know how to escape hash(#) symbol in kendo grid client template like this:-

```
\\#
```

But when I am trying to escape a hash in kendo nested grid it is not working probably because `\#` has special meaing in nested grid. But how can I escape it?

I tried `\\\\#`, `\\#\\#`,`\\##` but nothing worked. Has anyone faced such scenario?

Comment: Are you escaping it to be able to display that character? If yes, check this [site](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) and use code for that sign

Comment: @Ademar - No I am not trying to display a character, I am trying to call a JS function which is exposed by _jQuery data_ option like his:- `$("#foo").data("bar").myFunction();`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work if you do

```
\\\\\\#
```

that is:
`\\\\` is for the backslashes, because the template is treated as javascript, this will be truncated to `\\`. but for the reason that the `#` would also be interpreted as binding, you have to escape it separatley to `\\#`.

after the template is interpreted, the detailview will interpret `\\#` and your link or whatever you have that requires that escaping, will have the correct value.